# c# operators '??' and 'as'

Tags: c#, operators

I saw this code but i don't know order of operators in second line. What's result of second line?

`Object obj = 1;`

`String s = obj as String ?? "";`

Comment: empty string, because `obj as String` evaluates to `null`. btw, did you try to run it?

Comment: you can simply write this code and debug it

Comment: there's only two theoretically possible orders, and one of them doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: This question doesn't show any effort.  "What's result of second line?"  There are so many ways to try this.  For example, type `(object)1 as string ?? ""` into your immediate window (Ctrl+Alt+I)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C# operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) table states that `as` (see "relational and type-testing" row) operator has higher precedence then  null-coalescing operator (`??`), so your expression will result in empty string, because `obj as String` will evaluate to `null` thus null-coalescing operator will return right-hand operand, i.e. `""`.